# lambda to expression tree

Tags: c#, expression-trees

How do you convert the following lambda to expression tree?

```
source.Join(lookup, s => s.Id, l => l.Id, (s,l) => l)
```

I think I have everything covered except for the resultSelector (s, l) => l.

Here is my code .. Thanks!

```
public static IQueryable<TLookup> GetLookupSource<T, TLookup, TKey>(this IQueryable<T> source, IQueryable<TLookup> lookup{
   ParameterExpression s = Expression.Parameter(source.ElementType, "s");
   Expression<Func<T, TKey>> outerKeySelector = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, TKey>>(Expression.PropertyOrField(s, "Id"), s);

   ParameterExpression l = Expression.Parameter(lookup.ElementType, "l");
   Expression<Func<TLookup, TKey>> innerKeySelector = Expression.Lambda<Func<TLookup, TKey>>(Expression.PropertyOrField(l, "Id"), l);

   Expression<Func<T, TLookup, IQueryable<TLookup>>> resultSelector = null;//<---How to compose this

   MethodInfo joinMethod = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public).Where(m => m.Name == "Join" && m.GetParameters().Length == 5).First();
   var genericJoinMethod = joinMethod.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T), typeof(TLookup), typeof(TKey), typeof(IQueryable<TLookup>));
   var result = genericJoinMethod.Invoke(source, new object[] { source, lookup, outerKeySelector, innerKeySelector, resultSelector });
   return (IQueryable<TLookup>)result;
}
```

Comment: So, why don't you add the result selector? What's the problem you're having?

Comment: @ban-G, please never edit a question to include the answer.  **That is extremely confusing for everyone.**  The purpose of the site is to see the question, and then see the answer below.  Your action prevents that metaphor from working.  (I was very confused why Balazs' answer was useful since it was already the code contained in the question.)  Cheers.

Comment: Got it. Yeah, it made it confusing when I corrected the code. Thanks for reverting my changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this should do it:

```
var resultSelector = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, TLookup, TLookup>>(l, s, l);
```